# How can I check xcr0 register in QEMU session gdb?

Tags: x86, operating-system, gdb, qemu, osdev

I want to check the register value of my QEMU session in gdb. Currently, I cannot use qemu monitor due to I use -nographic. (I know there is option such as -mon :serial but currently I cannot enter to the qemu monitor with some other unknown problems.) Is there a command or any kind of method to view xcr0 register in gdb? If you know, please help me.

Comment: When you dont use qemu monitor, you can use only gdb commands. `info registers all` is the gdb command to show all registers in gdb.

Comment: Have you tried using BOCHS with its built-in debugger, instead of QEMU+GDB?

Comment: No I didn't I will try it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can't; QEMU does not currently expose this system register via the gdbstub interface.